# Get Rinkeby Ether For metamask wallet

Tags: ether, metamask, testnets, rinkeby

I am trying to get some Rinkeby ETH through for my Metamask wallet, I published my address into Facebook copied the link inserted it to https://faucet.rinkeby.io/ asked for Ether but it keeps on responding that there is no address to fund.

this is the address in case anyone can fund me: 0x45B02D8A20518FC7Ed843FcAa94ffA90301a61Bf

PS: my Facebook post is public

Any help will be appreciated thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have transferred 10ETH for your address, of course it is under Rinkeby network, wish you all the best!

Comment: Thank you for the ethers well received :D :D :D